# import package shows wrong error message for missing file

Tags: errors, import

When I use the the package `import` and the specified file in the command is missing, I get a wrong error message on my linux setup indicating that another file, that is present, is missing.  <s>But on Windows it works and correctly displays the missing file.</s> As pointed out in the comments it seems to be a problem either with the TexLive version or with the package itself.

MWE:

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
    \import{path}{non_existing_file}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex main.tex` on *linux* gives me

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./master.aux)

! LaTeX Error: File `master.aux' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: aux)

Enter file name:
```

However on *Windows* I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty) (./main.aux)

! LaTeX Error: File `non_existing_file.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name:
```

Comment: In Linux it appears that the TexLive (TL) version is `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5` and in Windows it is  `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3`. It may be worth a try at updating the Windows TL version and seeing if the errors are equal.

Comment: Ok, wow, after ` tlmgr update --all` on Windows (now also `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`) I am getting the same incorrect error. `import` package was also updated from revision number 17361 to 53932. So I suspect this could be a bug in the package itself. Where could I  github-like "open an issue"  for that?

Comment: You probably have the import version with a bug, The bug has been corrected already but the new version is imho not in texlive 2019 but only in texlive 2020 (which will be released in a few days).

Comment: It doesn't sound like the bug with handling a null path. I'll trace it. Your example suggests a macro holding the file name is not rewritten when the file is missing.

Comment: It works for me. ! LaTeX Error: File `path/non_existing_file.tex' not found. But I don't have the very latest LaTeX; is that it?

Comment: I don't know when it first appeared in LaTeX, but `\IfFileExists` was changed to do `\set@curr@file`, and the error message changed to to use `\@curr@file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, recent updates to LaTeX have rewritten internals for `\input` that now do auto-quoting of file names (always, not just when they contain spaces). That's excellent, but import.sty version 6.1 didn't match. Find version 6.2 soon -- It just went to CTAN.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I will try it after it's available on CTAN and accept the answer then.